# Do you think It is right approach to separate private function from class definition for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing

When I'm writing some typescript code, I wanted to unit test some private method of Foo Class.

```
class Foo {
   private privateMethodWantToTest(argument) {
      return 'Bar'
   }
}
```

So, I separated function like this:

```
export function privateMethodWantToTest(this: Foo, argument) {
   return 'Bar'
}

class Foo {
   private privateMethodWantToTest(argument) {
      return privateMethodWantToTest.call(this, argument) 
   }
}
```

This approach may work, but It's a bit redundant.
And exporting all function may be a bad idea.

What do you think about this approach ?
Is there better solution for unit test, or should't I test private method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  First, testing is about finding (or preventing) bugs.  Bugs are in the implementation details: Different implementations have different potential bugs.  For example, think about the different ways to implement a Fibonacci function: as iterative/recursive function, closed form expression (Moivre/Binet), lookup table: The interface is always the same, the possible bugs differ significantly.  Another way to understand this is that, when looking at coverage, you always look at the implementation, not the interface.

There are, however, other (secondary) goals for unit-testing, namely to have a robust test suite that does not break unnecessarily when implementation details change.  For example, if the name of a private function changed, it would be unfortunate if the unit-testing suite broke.  Therefore, often it is beneficial to test implementation details / private functions indirectly (that is, testing them via calls to the public interface).

But, even if tests are implemented against the public API and thus do not break when internals change, some changes to the internals can make the existing and still working tests useless: Tests for the Moivre/Binet implementation of Fibonacci will continue to work if you switch to a lookup table.  A lookup table will most likely, however, require a different testing approach.  The fact that the tests still work in this case does not mean the test suite does not have to be maintained.

As said, testing private methods / functions in tests has disadvantages, because it can make your tests fragile.  There are situations, however, when it is not practical to test these functions from the public API.  Then, the best tradeoff can still be to test the private functions separately (remember: primary goal is finding bugs, non-fragile test-suite is secondary goal).  You will, however, have to find ways to make the private methods accessible to your tests.  One possibility is, as you have shown, to make them public, and you can test them as public functions.

Note that this does not make your testsuite less fragile: Just making some implementation detail publicly accessible does not change its nature of being an implementation detail.  There is no magic like "replace private by public and implementation details become more stable".  Strictly speaking, you make an implementation detail accessible for the purpose of testing - not for the access from others.  This would be an architectural constraint and should be communicated, like, dont't use these classes / methods / functions.  One possibility is, to name them accordingly.

Comment: _testing is about finding (or preventing) bugs_ - not agree, automating testing is about to provide confidence to developers that application works as intended. If I wrote a bug I will wrote the tests which will prove my bug is a "feature by design"